# Quiero utilizar un par de varibles de una funcion en javascript, para concaternarlas en una nueva varriable

Tags: javascript, php, html5

Este es mi script, cuando invoco a mi funcion urlnow   desde html captura los datos ingresados por el usuario y esos datos quiero ocuparlos fuera de la funcion para concatenar una varible con url (Esta ya la tengo de manera global) para utilizarla en otra funcion

```
        <script>
                          let ruta = document.getElementById("rutaimg").value;
                          let tamano = document.getElementById("tamano").value;
                          let encoded = encodeURIComponent(ruta);
                          let url = "https://netrabbittests.link/publicidatest/exam.php?rutaimg=" + encoded + "&resultfuente=" + resfuente + "&tamano=" + tamano + "&texto1=" + tex1 + "&texto2=" + tex2 + "&texto3=" + tex3 + "" /////// estos valores ya vienen por defecto en el fomrulario que envio 
        
        
                          function urlnow() {
                            let numfuente = document.getElementById("selectfuente").value;
                            let resfuente = document.getElementById("resultfuente").value;
                            let tex1 = document.getElementById("texto1").value;
                            let tex2 = document.getElementById("texto2").value;
                            let tex3 = document.getElementById("texto3").value;
                            document.getElementById("nuevaimg").src = url;
                            console.log(url);
                          }
       

                          }
                        </script>
```

Comment: pasas `let url ="http.... ` para dentro de la función.....o es otra cosa?

Comment: esa variable let, lo voy a ocupar en otra funcion, la cual quiero que me mande la url completa concatenada con los valores extraidos de la funcion

Comment: Entonces NO colocas `let`, solo pones `url="https.....` al último de la función `urlnow`

Comment: Yo no entiendo... defines una variable url afuera de la funcion y la concatenas con unas avriables que no existen y que solo están definidas dentro de otra funcion

Comment: existen dentro de un formulario html, cuando se da click envia los valores mediante su id, para acompletar mi url

Comment: @Pipe puedes darme un ejemplo, por favor

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo cambiaría a algo asi:

```
let ruta = document.getElementById("rutaimg").value;
let tamano = document.getElementById("tamano").value;
let encoded = encodeURIComponent(ruta);
let url = "https://netrabbittests.link/publicidatest/exam.php"; //Solo defines la url base

function urlnow() {
  let numfuente = document.getElementById("selectfuente").value;
  let resfuente = document.getElementById("resultfuente").value;
  let tex1 = document.getElementById("texto1").value;
  let tex2 = document.getElementById("texto2").value;
  let tex3 = document.getElementById("texto3").value;
  document.getElementById("nuevaimg").src = url;

  //Concatenas las URL base con los parametros y devuelves el valor para ser usado por fuera donde quieras
  return url + "?rutaimg=" + encoded + "&resultfuente=" + resfuente + "&tamano=" + tamano + "&texto1=" + tex1 + "&texto2=" + tex2 + "&texto3=" + tex3 + "";
}

const value = urlnow(); //Capturas el valor devuelto
console.log(value); //Haces con él lo que quieras
```